# How to check for JWT token remaining validity time golang

Tags: go, jwt, express-jwt

I am setting the the expiration of JWT token claims using

```
claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(settings.Get().JWTExpiration)).Unix()
```

where settings.Get().JWTExpiration gives me the settings I have made in my application settings file.

I have written a function which should ideally give me the remaining time the token is valid for.

```
func getTokenRemainingValidity(timestamp interface{}) int {
    if validity, ok := timestamp.(float64); ok {
        tm := time.Unix(int64(validity), 0)
        remainder := tm.Sub(time.Now())
        if remainder > 0 {
            return int(remainder.Seconds() + expireOffset)
        }
    }
    return expireOffset
}
```

and I invoke this function like:

```
x := getTokenRemainingValidity(claims["exp"])
fmt.Println(x)
```

where claims["exp"] is the claims I have got after parsing a jwt token.
But this always gives me same output. i.e. `3600`. How can I check for the remaining validity of my token. I am using golang.

Comment: Just ask, why don't you just use a golang jwt package....

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `expireOffset` must be an int (because of the return), but `remainder.Seconds()` is a float64, so you can't add an int to it.
What is the value of expireOffset?
Also check that timestamp is indeed float64 and not Number: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number

Answer (score 0):

You always get 3600 (which seems to be the `expireOffset`) because the type assertion `timestamp.(float64)` fails, as the actual value of `timestamp` is `int64`.

```golang
func getTokenRemainingValidity(timestamp interface{}) int {
    var expireOffset = 3600
    if validity, ok := timestamp.(int64); ok {
        tm := time.Unix(int64(validity), 0)
        remainder := tm.Sub(time.Now())

        if remainder > 0 {
            return int(remainder.Seconds() + float64(expireOffset))
        }
    }
    return expireOffset
}
```

To make it work, I added the `expireOffset` and set it to 3600.
In the first return statement, `expireOffset` has to be convertet to `float64`, and then the result back to `int`.
This way it works, though I'm not sure for what you add or return the offset.

A full working example can be seen and tested [here on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RvfJAeRj5q3)  .